# Why MemberExpression for child's overridden property show parent's property

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes, linq-expressions

Let's assume we have 2 classes

```
class A{
   public abstract int Prop1 {get; set;}
}
```

and it's child

```
class Child : A{
   [CustomAttr(someval)] 
   override public int Prop1 {get; set;}
}
```

so later in my code I need to get this custom attribute's val.

```
bool haveCustomAttr(IExpression<Func<Child, int>> property){
    return ((MemberExpression)property.Body).Member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomAttr)).Any();
}
```

so when I call this code

```
haveCustomAttr(c => c.Prop1)
```

it's return `false` because `((MemberExpression)property.Body).Member` it's for some reason `A.Prop1` and not `Child.Prop1`

it's possible to fix with more advanced construction like this

```
((MemberExpression)property.Body).Expression.Type.GetMember(((MemberExpression)property.Body).Member
                .Name)[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomAttr), false).Any();
```

But it's still not clear for me why it's threat this expression as base class initially if it's clearly say that it's expression from `Child` class. Could someone explain logic behind this for me?

Comment: This is not specific to expression trees; the call within `property.Body` will end up being compiled as a call to `A.Prop1`, even if called through an expression of type `Child`. The vtable slot for that method is in `A` and `A` alone. Were `Child` to shadow this with a `new` declaration of the same name, the call would end up going to `Child`.